# Recursion Function that prints all possible binary permutations

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive function that generates all binary permutations with a given input of the amount of 'A' and 'B' elements that a string should have. For example function(a, b) when a = 2 and b = 2 should generate:
AABB
ABAB
ABBA
BAAB
BABA
BBAA
Would appreciate your help. Thanks!.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base case is the one where either `a` or `b` is zero, since there's only one permutation if you only have one element.  From there, the recursive call just needs to subtract one from either `a` or `b` to ensure that they will both eventually reach zero.

```
>>> def ab(a, b):
...     if not a:
...         return ["B" * b]
...     if not b:
...         return ["A" * a]
...     return ["A" + p for p in ab(a - 1, b)] + ["B" + p for p in ab(a, b - 1)]
...
>>> ab(2, 2)
['AABB', 'ABAB', 'ABBA', 'BAAB', 'BABA', 'BBAA']
```